# Creating Wordpress Page That Changes Content Based On Geolocation

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation

We are looking to create a series of landing pages that would be dedicated to different cities or states in the US.

I know that certain APIs are able to use geolocation to cater items such as maps or services in your area. **Would there be a way to populate cities and/or states based on a persons location onto a wordpress page?**

Comment: If you went about it "dynamically" which I think is what you are implying, I have severe doubts about negative (or at least not positive) SEO impact. Better I would have thought to make several, even hundreds, or standalone pages (linked) and some geolocation to send people to the right one. Thus they are all indexed.

Comment: I'd 2nd @mayersdesign opinion this this being potentially bad in terms of SEO. Also note that HTML5 geolocation (suggested in an answer) is blocked on recent version of chrome unless the connection is secured (https).

Comment: Thank you, i'll make sure to bring that to my bosses attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML5 geolocation.
Create WordPress pages as per City OR State and you can change front page on the basis of geolocation of person using the website.

Comment: You need to write a code to query database to change static front page of website while site is loading but it will help you to create a CMS site with proper content management and it will provide appropriate content to to end end user.

Comment: Note: on chrome 50 and above HTML5 geolocation is only available through a secure connection (https)

Comment: thank you RahuIN. 

I think I will work with the stand alone pages and some geolocation code after hearing about the impact to SEO.